# Getting Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) on Hackerearth, can't find out what's wrong in code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, online-compilation

I know its a invalid memory reference error, but I can't seem to find the cause of the error in my code.

I just tried my problem on Hackerearth, it was the 'Find Product' https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/find-product/
 and my submission was this, which gave me no errors on codeblocks compiler, but pops a Runtime Error(SIGSEGV).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int cases;
  int pro = 1;
  int product[1][cases];
  cin >> cases;
  for (int x = 0; x < cases; x++) {
    cin >> product[1][x];
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < cases; x++) {
    pro *= product[1][x];
  }
  cout << pro;
}
```

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: The compiler should give you a handful of (at least) warnings on that code. Do not ignore them.

Comment: You forgot to take modulo.

Comment: You're going to get the wrong answer later, because you haven't read and understood all the instructions.

Comment: You can solve this problem using only three integers; you don't need to store all the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

- Your `int product[1][cases];` is **before** `cin >> cases;`, so the input will not be used for allocation.
- You declared `int product[1][cases];`, so only `product[0]` is allowed and using `product[1]` is out-of-range (invalid).
- Variable-length array is not in C++ standard.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int cases;
  int pro = 1;
  cin >> cases;
  int* product = new int[cases];
  for (int x = 0; x < cases; x++) {
    cin >> product[x];
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < cases; x++) {
    pro *= product[x];
  }
  cout << pro;
  delete[] product;
}
```